# Difference between 冲昏 and 抓狂?

Tags: difference

It seems like both of them refer to going crazy because of something.

Ex. 别被她冲昏了头脑

Ex. 你让我快抓狂

Can someone please help me differentiate when you would use which?

Thanks

Comment: it is 冲昏头脑 and 抓狂，examining the examples at jukuu, will show that the former refers to swelling s.o.'s head, becoming dizzy (with success), s.th. going to s.o.'s head, the latter refers to simple craziness, frenzy, madness etc.

Comment: bkrs：冲昏头脑：lit. to be muddled in the brain (idiom); fig. excited and unable to act rationally
to go to one's head；become dizzy with success; turn sb.'s head (brain); have one's head turned; lose (go to) one's head:
胜利冲昏头脑 dizzy with success
chōnghūntóunǎo
turn sb.'s head  抓狂：
zhuā kuáng
to blow one's top
to be driven mad
to become frantic
zhuā kuáng
闽南方言。指一时失去控制，做出失常的行为。

Comment: difference can be traced to that between  **昏**  and  **狂** ：（汉语水平考试词典） **冲** ：［义１］满；足（sufficient；full）：～斥｜～其量｜～裕｜～耳不闻｜填～｜晚会～满着欢乐的气氛｜熬了一夜，双眼有点儿～血。**昏** ［义３］神志不清楚；糊里糊涂（dazed and confused；dizzy）～乱｜～沉沉｜发～｜酒喝多了，感到有点儿头～眼花。 **抓** ：［义１］手指并拢，把物体固定在手中（seize；grab）～瞎｜～药｜幸好他～住栏杆才没有掉下去｜打破了～举全国记录。**狂** ：［义３］精神失常（mad）丧心病～｜他发～似的大喊大叫｜汽车疯～地冲向人海。

Answer (score 1):

[image]

All means mad，but different types of mad.

“冲昏” means you are so mad that you have already lost your mind.

“抓狂”means you are so mad but you do not know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

They are very different. 冲昏 means that someone is overwhlemed with certain emotion and cannot think critically. This does not mean he/she is mentally broken. 抓狂 is just crazy.

Answer (score 0):

冲昏 : happening/emotions that overwhelm someone that will cause irrational consequences..

example:

```
他让一时的胜利冲昏了头， 令他犯下了不可补救的错误。
The winning overwhelm him and cause him to make a big blunder.

他让贪念冲昏了头， 把所有储蓄都都抛进去庞氏骗局的投资计划。
Greed overwhelm him, which make him pour all his live saving on Ponzi scheme.

怒火冲昏了他的头， 导致他犯下更大错误 。
The overwhelming angers cause him make even bigger mistake.
```

抓狂 ：things/people/action that drive someone crazy, or causing frustration.

example:

```
那些碎碎念令他抓狂 
Those nagging drive him crazy

他常在会议中说出让人抓狂的话
He always say  something that drive everybody crazy during the meeting.
```

Answer (score -1):

我作为一名中国人来回答你：“冲昏”重在表示你的负面情绪影响你的判断力，而“抓狂”则重在表示你的负面情绪影响你的行为。

Comment: Please use English+Chinese for foreigners' understanding.